# Regex expression of Positiove,Negative decimal numbers

Tags: regex

Im trying to figure out regular expression for negative and positive decimal numbers.

for example -

```
-11 = true
11 = true
-11.11 = true
11.11 = true
```

I thought about

```
(-)?([0-9])+(.)?([0-9])*|0
```

but it doesn't work well.

Any ideas ? Thanks.

Comment: `-?\d+(\.\d+)?`

Comment: *...but it doesn't work well.* explain it.

Answer (score 0):

try `-?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]*)?`. Make sure you escape that period character!

https://regex101.com/r/FFPEUA/1

Answer (score 0):

```
-?([0-9]*(\.[0-9]*)?|\.[0-9]+)
```

This is an or-regex. The left side catches any integer and decimal constructed by integer followed by . followed by more digits. The right side catches numbers written as . followed by digits.